# how to rewriting url for shared hosting of godaddy sub folders

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite URL of my sub folders.

I have `mysite.php/subfolder/login/index.php` where i want to rewrite the url into any     encrypted format or want latest `mysite.php/login/index.php` where i want to hide the sub folder

Hope any can help i tried with ,htaccess but it didn't work ..

I also added .htaccesss to root by adding code

```
RewriteRule ^login\/index\.php$ /subfolder/login/index.php [L]
```

I'm able to hide the sub folder but the css of the `index.php` is not working.

Comment: This question is barely intelligible. You should phrase it in a manner that allows it to be understood by human beings.

Comment: Probably the best way to fix this is to not use godaddy ... I've had problems with trying to do things like that ... PHP.ini and .htaccess are extremely temperamental when using godaddy ... Try set up a test server, and see if your .htaccess works correctly

Comment: what i mean is its working where i am able to rewrite the url but after rewriting it, css file in the folder login is not working ..